# Making it Easier for Older Users to Login to Multiple Accounts

Tags: passwords, login, password-management, credentials

I currently do consulting for a small business that has multiple applications that they need to login too.

I'm trying to get them to start using [Basecamp](http://basecamp.com) and [Zendesk](http://zendesk.com) to make all of our lives easier when it comes to collaboration on big projects and quick helpdesk ticket items.

However, I have recently been informed that it is difficult for them to remember all of these websites etc... to login too.  However the login information is the same.

Right now they have to login to:

Windows Login
Gmail

I want them additionally to login to
Basecamp
Zendesk

This is just a generation or two gap between myself and them, so I'm wondering what others do to solve these problems.

Is there some way we could configure USB thumbdrives that somehow have Lastpass or something on that when plugged into the computer automatically log them into their Windows account, then when they were to say visit the Basecamp account would automatically log them into that?

I think the security risk (of a list thumbdrive) is well worth the ability to use these extra applications.

Unless anyone else has any other ways for making it easier for users to login to multiple sites.

Comment: I think I found something [Rohos](http://www.rohos.com/support/knowledge-base/how-to-set-up-usb-flash-drive-for-secure-windows-login/) I'm just wondering what the security problems that could arise from using this. We can get over losing the key if we use two factor authorization (my users can remember a pin) using this program combined with lastpass should almost solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rohos](http://www.rohos.com/support/knowledge-base/how-to-set-up-usb-flash-drive-for-secure-windows-login/)

Rohos is what I decided to go with.

Answer (score 0):

[Roboform](http://www.roboform.com/) maintains a list of website addresses and login credentials.  When you go to the website, it logs you in automatically.  If you prefer, you can look at the list of saved logins in Roboform and just click on your choice to enter the web address and log in all in one step.  Finally, it will save identity info, i.e. name, address, phone number, and does a great job of filling in forms with that info on any website.

There is also a version (Roboform2Go) that runs from a USB drive.

It's free and work great with IE or Firefox.  Unfortunately it does not integrate well with Chrome - most websites fail to trigger the automatic form fill and log in.